# Core Location not requesting user permission

Tags: ios, core-location

An application I was testing asked for user location on first device launch. I have uninstalled the application, deleted the build folder, and cleaned all targets, but core location never requests permission again. It is just off and must be enabled in the users settings. Any idea why the users choice would remain persistent even after the application was uninstalled? Very weird behavior, worried it may get me rejected for the store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not many people know this, but after you uninstall an application, that application's documents and preferences are still stored on the device, here:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Safe Harbor/myappidentifier/Container/
```

in my opinion, this was not a wise move by apple, as that could have security risks, as the one you have explained above.

If an app is re-installed, iOS automatically copies those preferences back into the appropriate folder. That is the cause of the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Is this on the device or the mac? While the device is connected, I cannot find the folder on the Macintosh HD. I do not know of any way to explore the file system of the device itself. How would I get to this folder to delete the appropriate cache?

Comment: You will need to jailbreak your device, and SSH into it. That is the only way I know of to delete that folder, apple has locked down most access to folders, even to developers.

Comment: Holy bejesus, that's not the answer I was expecting. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I am not sure, but you might be able to restore the device for this, no promises though.