# Delegate methods not being called, can't see why

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

**FIXED: I was creating my CLLocationManager in the viewDidLoad method, so it was being cleaned by ARC almost immediately.  I changed my instance to be a class instance instead of method instance and the problem is solved.**

I have a class, an NSObject, which I'm using to control the entering and exiting of beacon regions.

It's implementation is here:

```
#import "dcBeaconManager.h"

@implementation dcBeaconManager

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){}
    return self;
}

bool testRanging = true;
bool firstRegionEntered = true;

- (void)initBeaconManager {
    NSLog(@"initBeaconManager called");
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"digiConsRegion"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)stopBeaconManager {
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Started looking for regions");
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Region discovered");
    if (firstRegionEntered) {
        NSLog(@"First time in region");
        firstRegionEntered = false;
    }
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Region left");
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"We hope you enjoyed the event, thank you for coming.";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"locationManager initiated");
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [beacons lastObject];
    //Store some information about this beacon
    NSNumber *currentBeaconMajor = beacon.major;  //it's major (group) number
    NSNumber *currentBeaconMinor = beacon.minor;  //it's minor (individual) number

    if (([currentBeaconMinor floatValue] == 59204) && ([currentBeaconMajor floatValue] == 33995) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        NSLog(@"Mint discovered");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLocateMint" object:nil];
    } else if (([currentBeaconMinor floatValue] == 7451) && ([currentBeaconMajor floatValue] == 63627) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        NSLog(@"Blue discovered");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLocateBlue" object:nil];
    } else if (([currentBeaconMinor floatValue] == 51657) && ([currentBeaconMajor floatValue] == 26976) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        NSLog(@"Purple discovered");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLocatePurple" object:nil];
    }

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    if (testRanging) {
        NSLog(@"Testing: forced ranging");
        if ([region isEqual:self.beaconRegion] && state == CLRegionStateInside) {
            [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Here's the header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface dcBeaconManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

//properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;  //used to define which beacons we are looking for
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;  //set up location services and allow beacons to be found

//methods
- (void)initBeaconManager;
- (void)stopBeaconManager;


@end
```

Now, this code has worked fine before when included in the main view controller, but I'm trying to get better at OOP in Obj-C.  The logs show the object is created and the main initBeaconManager is called, but from there is just stops.  I cannot figure out why.  Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Comment: A side note, have you checked wether location services are turned ON?

Comment: You mean on the device? Yes, they are on :)

Comment: First use, iOS ask for your permission to use your location (Allow/Don't Allow), I assume you allowed it then.

Comment: I did.  However, interestingly, now when I re-compile and run it doesn't ask and the services are turned off.  If I manually turn them on it's still not working, but this must be close to the issue.

Comment: Just discovered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098301/core-location-not-requesting-user-permission

Comment: Tested on a new device, it doesn't ask for permission for location services.  This has to be the error.

Comment: Don't hesitate to post your own answer and to mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this help but can you replace this line:

```
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"digiConsRegion"];
```

with that one:

```
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 minor:2 identifier:@"digiConsRegion"];
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = entry;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = exit;
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
```

I believe you need to provide major and minor values for bacon region.

Comment: The major and minor need to be declared when creating a beacon out of the device but not for listening for a beacon.  Sadly this didn't help :/  But thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating my CLLocationManager in my viewDidLoad method, and ARC was killing it off almost immediately.  Moving it to be a class instance instead of a method instance fixed the problem.