# core location not asking permission

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

problem :

For some reason, the app I’m working on is not asking for permission to use location services. This used to work before. Also, I created a new project in which I followed the steps described below EXACTLY in which this worked immediately.

One difference is I know the authorization status in the main app I’m working on is .Denied, it was .NotDetermined in the test project.

I read this answe on stack overflow :

[Core Location not requesting user permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098301/core-location-not-requesting-user-permission)
'
Not many people know this, but after you uninstall an application, that application's documents and preferences are still stored on the device, here:

/var/mobile/Library/Safe Harbor/myappidentifier/Container/
in my opinion, this was not a wise move by apple, as that could have security risks, as the one you have explained above.

If an app is re-installed, iOS automatically copies those preferences back into the appropriate folder. That is the cause of the behavior you are seeing.
'
This could explain it because I did reinstall the app but it doesn't say how to solve it.

Thank you

Here’s the relevant code i wrote in the App :

I set the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in info.plist

I imported core location :

```
import CoreLocation
```

implemented the right protocol:

```
CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

set this property :

```
var locationManager  = CLLocationManager()
```

set the delegate in ViewDidLoad

```
locationManager.delegate = self
```

and wrote a test function to test this :

```
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
println("Location Services Enabled")
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Authorized {
            println("Location Services Authorized")
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            println("Location Services Authorized WHEN IN USE")
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            println("Location Services NOT Authorized: NOT DETERMINED")
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Restricted {
            println("Location Services NOT Authorized: RESTRICTED")
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied {
            println("Location Services NOT Authorized: DENIED")
        } else {
            println("Location Services NOT Authorized")
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

    } else {
        println("!!! Location Services NOT Enabled !!!")
    }
```

Console Output :

```
Location Services Enabled
Location Services NOT Authorized
```

Comment: Core Location only asks once. It never asks again after that. You are not allowed to ship an app that requires Core Location and you are not allowed to keep on asking for it if the user says no. Once disabled, users must go into settings to activate it — but your app will be rejected by the app store review team if you pop up an alert message telling them to do so. It has to be done in an unobtrusive way (eg, an error icon that shows the alert after users tap it)

Comment: my intention was not to ask for permission after permission was denied. The app never asked for permission. I just deleted and reinstalled it

Comment: Uninstalling an app on any Apple platform will not reset your settings. Only Microsoft Platforms do that. If it asked for permission on a previous install, it will remember that.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into the Settings app, General, and reset Location & Privacy to get the initial permission dialog for your app again.  Otherwise, iOS saves the first answer without ever asking again.

Comment: I have this issue with core location that I am not getting the location service popup at any time even after uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Also in Setting -> Apps -> MyApp there is no location service to on/off. I have used 4 keys in info.plist with strings defining why i am using these keys. Can you help me out @hotpaw2